# Bash/zsh: Undo erase backwards (ctrl+w)

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

In Bash and Zsh <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> erases backwards from where the cursor is. Is it also possible to undo what I had erased?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://teohm.com/blog/2012/01/04/shortcuts-to-move-faster-in-bash-command-line/ for this and more shortcuts

Comment: for reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Bare-Essentials

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Undo it's like this :
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd>

Comment: `ctrl+shift+-` to get the underscore.

Comment: "ctrl + y" == "ctrl + _" work's the same

Comment: Yes, both will work.

Comment: In this instance they will both work, but they don't mean the same thing. Ctrl + y means "yank".

Comment: ctl+/, however, *is* an additional binding for "undo".  Which is good for my emacs-accustomed fingers.

Comment: `CTRL` + `-` (minus sign) works the same for me. Tested in both Ubuntu 16 and an older version. (Actually in Mint from 2014, which is branched off of some older version of Ubuntu. `uname -r` says it's 3.13.0-143-generic.) I am sshed in via PuTTY, but, I don't think that should matter; it's still bash reacting to the character codes I'm sending it, right?

Comment: what is redo then ?

Comment: source: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Bare-Essentials

Answer (score 21):

It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> (or <kbd>_</kbd>) pastes what's in the buffer. The buffer gets filled by things like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>w</kbd>. You can paste it in different places multiple times, so it's not an "undo". <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> is *undo*, and you can execute it multiple times to undo every consecutive previous action.

Answer (score 6):

This below shortcut key does the job of undo the erased string by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>,

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! Where is the difference to ctrl+_?

Comment: `ctrl+shift+-` to get the underscore.

Comment: @DamianFill, it looks that this command simply pastes the last text deleted with whatever command. So you cannot do several undos to restore several deleted portions of text

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> does not delete but cuts everything in front of the cursor. Therfore you can yank/paste it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> assuming you did not move the cursor. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> actually restores the line itself.