# Redo keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu shell (Bash)?

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

[There is a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444966/bash-zsh-undo-erase-backwards-ctrlw) about the undo keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> can do this.

Is there a redo keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a redo keyboard shortcut?

Not directly in Bash, as mentioned already in [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1439072/1165986).

However, when editing more complicated command-lines, you might want to open it in an editor that *can* provide redo functionality (and more).  Bash uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> keybinding (when using default keybindings) or <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (for vi keybindings) to open the current command-line in your selected editor (by default, Nano, in Ubuntu).

You can then use the undo/redo commands from your editor.

After editing the command-line, exiting the editor will execute the command.

To change the default editor system-wide, use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

To override just for your user, set the `EDITOR` environment variable to the path of your preferred editor.

---

Site-note:  Do use caution with this feature -- As mentioned in [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85391/where-is-the-bash-feature-to-open-a-command-in-editor-documented#comment1039008_85393), any editor exiting with a success (0 return code) will cause the command to be executed in its last saved state, which could be unexpectedly dangerous.

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1601690/1210833) for a potential workaround (which I have not tested personally).  Also note that some other shells (Zsh and Fish, at least) do not *execute* the command on exit, but simply paste it into the command line, then requiring an <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute.  This is, IMHO, much safer default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You have to redo yourself what you undid.

Comment: why i don’t under stand

Comment: Because nobody implemented that. Perhaps it makes little sense to have a redo command for editing an interactive command. For more complex commands you can use an editor.