# How to configure Ubuntu terminal to jump/select words on Ctrl(+Shift)+Left and Ctrl(+Shift)+Right?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, ssh, shortcut-keys, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I use Windows 11, but I also have Ubuntu running in WSL or when connecting with SSH.

In Windows PowerShell terminal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> jumps a word to the left or right.  Adding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key *selects* the word to the left or right (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>).

In WSL Ubuntu terminal, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> jumps one word to the left and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> one word to the right, but pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> does not select.

In SSH (PuTTY) terminal, neither <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> nor <kbd>Shift</kbd> have any effect.

How can I configure WSL and SSH (PuTTY) to behave like PowerShell terminal, which is extremely convenient.

**EDIT 1**

I use Windows Terminal to run Windows Powershell, Powershell Core and WSL. Its version is 1.12.10732.0

Answer (score 3):

*Short answer:*

I would recommend upgrading to Windows Terminal, the (relatively) new terminal replacement in Windows.  In new installations of Windows 11 22H2, it is now the default terminal for PowerShell, CMD, WSL, and any other "console-mode" application.

The latest release of Windows Terminal (1.15) has added support for "Mark mode", which is probably the closest you will get to the functionality you are requesting.  You can activate mark-mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (which is configurable).  Once activated, you can then use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+(<kbd>Shift</kbd>)+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> keybindings to move and select words.

---

*Explanation:*

First, it's important to understand the difference between the *Shell* and the *Terminal*:

- PowerShell and Bash (in Ubuntu in WSL) are *shells*, which are really just specialized text/console-mode applications for interfacing with *other* text/console-mode applications (such as Linux `ls` or Windows `ipconfig.exe`).

  Inside the shell, there's an input handler for processing the actual keystrokes.  This is typically the Linux `readline` library for Bash in Ubuntu.  In recent PowerShell releases, it's [PSReadline](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine).
- A *terminal*, on the other hand, is the windowed application inside which your text-mode applications run.

  Windows provides two built-in terminals in the latest release:

  - The Windows Console Host is the legacy, 25-year old or so terminal that you are likely seeing when running either PowerShell or Ubuntu/WSL.
  - Windows Terminal is the (fairly) new replacement.  It's modern, open-source, feature-rich, and customizable -- None of which apply to the older Console Host.  It's the default terminal starting with new installations of Windows 11 22H2, and can be set as the default in Windows 11 21H2.

  It also runs just fine under Windows 10, but not as "default".  For instance, you can run PowerShell by starting Windows Terminal and launching the PowerShell profile, but just running "PowerShell" from the Start menu will use the older Console Host.

There are quite a few third-party terminals for Windows as well, and even more for Linux.

PuTTY is a bit of a hybrid, since it bundles both its terminal and text-mode application (the SSH client) into one.  But the features are actually separate:

- `pterm.exe` provides the terminal functionality without the SSH client
- `plink.exe` provides the SSH client that you can run in a different terminal

---

##### So what the heck does this have to do with selecting words?!

Ah, we're getting there ;-).  When you press any key in Windows, it has to get processed *somewhere*:

- First, a key might be handled by Windows itself.  For instance, pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> tells Windows to switch/cycle between open windows/applications.  If a key is handled by Windows itself, it typically isn't sent to any other application.
- Next<sup>1</sup>, the keystroke is sent to the *application*, which is the *terminal* in your case.  Console Host doesn't handle many keys itself, but Windows Terminal includes a large number of keybindings, most all of which are customizable.  For instance, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in Windows Terminal will open a new tab with the default profile.

  <sub><sup>1</sup> I'm over-simplifying here.  It's possible for other applications to "hook" the keyboard as well.</sub>
- If a key isn't handled by the terminal, then the terminal is going to send it on to the text/console application (shell), or more accurately its input handler (or whatever other application is running, such as `vim`/`nano`/etc.).

  This is what is happening with your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> keys.

##### So can I configure Bash, the shell, to select words using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> like PowerShell?

Unfortunately, no.  Keep in mind that *Windows* PowerShell has pretty much always existed in an environment where there is a *known* clipboard (the Windows clipboard).  That means that it (and its readline) could always assume that you *can* select and copy text to the clipboard using the keyboard.

Bash, on the other hand, started out as a pure-console application that could be used without any graphical, windowing system.  It can run in a pure-console (no clipboard), Windows (`clip.exe`), X (where text might be passed to `xsel`), macOS, and others.  There's just no mechanism in place for it to copy to a clipboard.  Some other text-mode applications have implemented a configurable clipboard option where you could configure (for example), `clip.exe` to be the clipboard application to receive copied text, but Bash has not done this.

So we come back to my original suggestion -- Use Windows Terminal, which does provide this capability, albeit with slightly less convenient keybindings since you have to first get into mark-mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

---

##### What about PuTTY?

I'm not aware of any way to configure PuTTY to do this, but I'm going to mostly skip it since:

- I haven't used PuTTY since WSL came out.  The OpenSSH client in Ubuntu provides everything I need, and the config files for OpenSSH are much more portable than those for PuTTY (which stores information in the Windows registry by default).
- Regardless, the configuration of hotkeys *in* PuTTY would be a bit off-topic here on Ask Ubuntu unless we were covering configuring the Ubuntu/Bash shell inside it.

With that in mind, I'd personally recommend what I've done -- Since you are already using Ubuntu in WSL, just transition to the OpenSSH client there if it fits your workflow.  Then you can use Windows Terminal for all your needs -- PowerShell, WSL, and SSH -- With tabs and mark-mode for all.

Comment: I already use WT, but I understand I need to update it.

Comment: @mark Excellent - Then that makes it easy! ;-)

Comment: I have just upgraded to 1.15. I can see the mark mode in action. But pressing delete does not actually delete the selection. It does place it to clipboard, though.

Comment: @mark Hmmm.  Deleting probably isn't going to be possible through mark-mode.  That's a case where the terminal can't tell the shell itself what to *change*, just select, copy, and exit back to the way that the screen was before mark-mode.

Comment: @mark Consider [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1440559/1165986) for more complicated editing of the command-line in Bash (and other shells).  That will allow you to use an editor to make changes to the command-line.  The default Ubuntu nano editor does use Ctrl+Shift+Left/Right to select words, but then you would use Ctrl+K to delete (the Del key itself still only erases one character).  There may be another editor out there that you could define for Bash that would give you exactly what you are looking for, however.

Comment: @mark Personally, I'm used to `vi` and its keybindings, where I can just hit the `v` key to enter "visual selection" mode, then `w` or `b` to select forward or backward.  A few less finger-gymnastics if you are a keyboard junky ...

Comment: Looks like I took a lot of thing for granted on windows ....